# how to introduce ecg.mat files asinput to a FIR filter's input

Tags: input, signals, simulink

i am working on ECG files which got them from  "http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/" .
i try to analysis  these files in matlab's simulink.
but i can not introduce these files as an input (for example) to an FIR filter.
haw can i do this?!
thanks for helping.
regards.

Answer (score 0):

convert it MAT file ol XLS file using mitdb tools.